# Why is fbevents.js loading on my page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, web, html

I'm having trouble with fbevents.js, I don't know why but is loading with my page, I'm nor importing it anywhere neither putting it inside a script tags referencing it.

Image from my page:

[image: Image from my page]

What do you guys think could be the problem?

Comment: did you add any fb plugins ?

Comment: That’s the script for Facebook Pixel event tracking. If you did not embed it directly, then maybe something in the background does (another plugin/extension, …)

Comment: Your page or a module in your page is including one of Facebook's api libraries, eg "Login with Facebook"

Comment: I didn´t add any fb plugins, I already looked everywhere, btw this is my page [Link](https://upet.co/)

Comment: i guess that come from FB pixels when considering 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js' you may check your header codes ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://staticw2.yotpo.com/QxG0HurQF664N9LddhiDMsxHjx9XYsaVgWcDBnme/widget.js

above `widget.js` script load `fbevent.js`.

here is the related code line. view source and search for `fbevent`.you can find that line.

```
(window,document,"script","//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js"
```

Comment: @DanielFJaramillo my pleasure

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem and in my case I noticed it is one of the scripts loaded by the Google Tag Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah GTM contained a section for fb code so just pause that in GTM studio and its fixed